# Problema con datatables y elemento card-body [un elemento HTML se sale fuera de otro]

Tags: css, datatable, bootstrap, overflow

Lo mas probable es que me falte subir codigo de algun archivo, pero dejo imagenes para que entiendan qué es lo que me sucede, y si quieren el codigo de algun elemento especifico me dicen y lo subo.

El problema me pasa en todas las paginas que contienen una `dataTable`, estas se renderizan dentro de un elemento con la class `card-body` de boostrap4.

> Código del dataTable

```
/*==================================================
Data Table
==================================================*/
$(".tablas").DataTable({

"pageLength": 10,
"language": {
    "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
    "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
    "sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
    "sEmptyTable": "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla =(",
    "sInfo": "Registros del _START_ al _END_ - Total: _TOTAL_",
    "sInfoEmpty": "Registros del  del 0 al 0 - Total: 0",
    "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de _MAX_ registros)",
    "sInfoPostFix": "",
    "sSearch": "Buscar:",
    "sUrl": "",
    "sInfoThousands": ",",
    "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
    "oPaginate": {
        "sFirst": "Primero",
        "sLast": "Último",
        "sNext": "Siguiente",
        "sPrevious": "Anterior"
    },
    "oAria": {
        "sSortAscending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
        "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
    },
    "buttons": {
        "copy": "Copiar",
        "colvis": "Visibilidad"
    }
}

});
```

> CSS del `card-body` - (Esto no lo escribi yo, lo trae por defecto la plantilla `AdminLTE3`)

```
.card-body {
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    padding: 1.25rem;
}
```

> Este es el código del footer (no creo que tenga que ver con el problema pero igual lo pongo)

```
 <!-- /.content-wrapper -->

 <footer class="main-footer text-center mb-0">
     <div class="float-right d-none d-sm-block">
         <b>Version</b> 1.0.0
     </div>
     <strong>Copyright &copy; 2020 <a href="mailto:agustinguerr4@gmail.com" target="_blank">Agustin Guerra</a>.</strong>
     Todos los derechos reservados
 </footer>
```

> Este es el `html` de uno de los tantos `card-body` que tengo (todos tienen el mismo problema)

```
  <div class="card-body">
          <table class="table table-bordered table-striped dt-responsive  tablaIngredientes" width="100%">

                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width:10px">#</th>
                        <th>Ingrediente</th>
                        <th>Unidad de Medida</th>
                        <th>Precio de Costo</th>
                        <th>Acciones</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>




            </table>
        </div>
```

> Ahora paso a mostrarles lo que me sucede. Reitero, si necesitan mas codigo solo haganmelo saber en los comentarios, no queria cargar la pregunta de codigo que esté de más, tal vez el problema está en un simple detalle y no me doy cuenta.
>
> Me sucede que el `card-body` llega hasta un punto y no crece mas, por lo que los elementos del `dataTable` en un momento se desbordan, chocando con el `footer` y dando una pésima experiencia para el usario

[image: Este es el card-body]

[image: Este es el contenido que se desborda del card-body]

[image: Asi se comienza a ver cuando se cargan mas de 8 elementos]

> Está claro que puedo solucionar esto limitando la cantidad maxima de elementos a mostrar por pagina, si lo dejo en 5 mi pagina nunca va a tener scroll hacia abajo por ende nunca va a existir este problema. Pero la idea es que el usuario pueda elegir cuantos elementos mostrar por pagina, entonces me gustaria poder arreglar esto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo general yo utilizo esta línea:

```html
div class="modal-body" class="text-center">
          <div class="container-fluid bd-example-row">
            <div class="modal-title"><h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">DATOS DEL RESGUARDANTE ACTUAL</h5></div>
            <table   class="table table-striped" table-bordered responsive class="display" style="width:100%">
```

cambia la línea que tienes como "`card-body`" por "`modal-body`" .

haber si te resuelve el problema que traes.

Comment: Wow, cuando lei tu respuesta pense que no tenia sentido, ya que tengo un card-header, card-body, y card-footer, pero definitivamente tenes razon! Cambiando eso se arregló, y probando en otras paginas se solucionó todo :) Muchas gracias

Comment: @Mani de nada me da mucho gusto que te haya resuelto este inconveniente,  son gajes de este oficio detalles de sintaxis,palabras etc etc te ponen de cabeza al suelo... Buen fin!!.